# How can I make a startup script (linux) to load all of my programs (dameons) on startup?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

For example, I need to have the following script be executed on startup

```
service httpd start
service mysqld start
service sshd start
service pure-ftpd start
/usr/local/bin/noip2 start
```

I do NOT want to make an alias in the init.d folder for each and every program.  Rather, can i make one text file to have all of these be called.  That would be so much easier.  Thank you!

Comment: You know there's a reason for those links in init.d. They allow the system to run the programs at startup but it ALSO shuts them down properly when the comp is being shut down.

Comment: -1 There's reasons things are done the way they are. You're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a script to startup te services. Under RedHat-based distributions (which is what it appears you are using), running this:

```
chkconfig servicename on
```

Will automatically create the symlinks for startup for the appropriate run levels (In this case (3 to 5). Under debian-based distributions, you would do

```
update-rc.d servicename defaults
```

To do the same thing. In fact, you can also reorder you start priorities with this tool as well:

```
update-rc.d servicename defaults 91
```

With upstart (which is what current version of Ubuntu is using and what Red Hat is moving to), you can even add dependancies so that one process will start only after a specific service is up. More info here:

```
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
```

At any event, if you don't want to use either of those mechanism, you can always use /etc/rc.local to start up your scripts. Unless there is a very good reason, just work with the tools that is already provided by your distro - it very likely better than what you can come up.

Answer (score 3):

Create a script with your commands and then add a cron job with @reboot like so:

crontab -e

@reboot /path/to/script

Comment: Oh cool. I never knew that one. Fancy.

Answer (score 1):

You can add those lines to `/etc/rc.local`. Note that it is run as 'root'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a single script with each of those very commands in it in the init.d folder. I've done similar and it worked smashingly.

Flagged for move to Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bash script containing those commands and put it in the /etc/init.d/ directory.

Lets say you called it FOO. You then run

```
% update-rc.d FOO defaults
```

You also have to make the file you created, FOO, executable, using

```
$chmod +x FOO
```

http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/

http://floppix.ccai.com/scripts1.html

Comment: He didn´t state he wanted to avoid the init.d directory entirely, just wanted to avoid creating a link for each one of the daemons